# Are there academic papers on the 'term structure' of adverse selection for futures and options?

Tags: options, futures, high-frequency, market-microstructure

By term structure I mean a **non-stationarity** in the pattern of **intraday adverse selection** as a given instruments approaches its **expiry**. Note that I am interested in the adverse selection on the instrument itself, not the underlying.

On the empirical side, I've seen myself a significant uptick of the price impact on S&P500 E-mini futures in the week leading into expiry. I am interested in understanding if that empirical observation is linked to a general decrease of liquidity as people rotate out of the instrument, or if there is something else in play.

References on models, whether theoretical or empirical would be greatly appreciated!